# Ubuntu installation alongside Windows 10 in desktop PC

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

I just bought my new desktop PC. The configuration is corei5-7500 processor, 8GB DDR4 RAM, WD 1TB 7200RPM HDD, motherboard=MSI Bazooka

I have Windows 10 pre-installed. Now I want to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS alongside Windows 10 (dual boot). But when I try to install Ubuntu with a USB flash drive, I get an error message like

> BGRT ignoring, failed to map image memory.

After that my desktop goes black and my monitor shows "no signal"
I waited in this condition for even a whole night assuming the installation will start at sometime, but nothing happens.
What will I do?

Comment: This could be a problem with the software on the Ubuntu USB flash drive. What program did you use to make the Ubuntu USB flash drive?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to:

- install from different USB stick or from DVD
- if still will not boot, load default settings in BIOS